# excel - macOS - enable macros in a macro free workbook

Tags: excel, macos

Any help would be appreciated.

Question:

- How do I open an .xlsx and enable macros in that workbook to run but not globally like this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-for-mac-c2494c99-a637-4ce6-9b82-e02cbb85cb96 (plus this doesn't work with a macro free .xlsx file)

Details:

- I have a macOS excel workbook that I created a working macro in
- when saving it gives me two options, save as a macro free and macro enabled.  The macro free is (.xlsx) while macro enabled is (.xlsm).
- once saved. When opening the .xlsx file the file opens and the macros do not work (macro free), however in the Visual Basic editors shows macros that I created do show up.
- opening .xlsm the macros work.
- searching I found https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-for-mac-c2494c99-a637-4ce6-9b82-e02cbb85cb96

  - issue is that this enable is for the entire excel environment plus it doesn't enable it for the .xlsx file.

Comment: You can't save macros in an ,xlsx workbook. The macros that you may see in the VB Editor right after you saved the file as .xlsx are not actually present in the file.

Comment: @bigben - thanks for the response.  If they are not there why do the show in the file?  Do I have to re-add them to the xlsx again to make them work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the answer is the following:

- So saving VB free actually removes all the VB scripts.  I mistakenly looked at the wrong workbook
- Solution

  - xlsm - VB enabled files will have to be saved in format
  - xlsx - if you want to keep VB enabled. You will have to re-add it in the VB editor by adding the module again.